# How do I get the value of each ListItem in a ListBox using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a ListBox that's dynamically populated.  I'd like to mark each selected ListItem as "selected" if the value of the ListItem matches a specific string of characters.

ASP.NET:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstComputers" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

C#:

```
//code that populates lstComputers.
//I got this part working properly already
```

Javascript:

```
//I'm really bad at javascript, so here's the sudo code of what I'd like done
For each ListItem in lstComputers{
  If ListItem.value like 'HP%' then{  //assuming % is like a wild card in SQL
    ListItem.selected = true;
  }
}
```

Please help me out with the JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: Please check my update, Just noticed that you need to mark the option if it *matches* some specific string, earlier I had done for exact string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
function SelectListBox() {
        var lstComputers = document.getElementById("<%= lstComputers.ClientID %>");
        for (var i = 0; i < lstComputers.options.length; i++) {
            if (lstComputers.options[i].text.indexOf("HP") > -1) {
                lstComputers.options[i].selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, Please make sure you have `SelectionMode` property set to `Multiple` if you want multiple selection in ListBox control.

Answer (score 0):

The Asp.net ListBox will generate the html of Select Tag and we can access that select element and its option in javascript using jQuery easily.

Following is the Javascript code that will do your work.

```
<script>   
 $("#lstComputers option").each(function(){

      var option = $(this);
    if(option.text().indexOf('HP') == 0)
    {
      option.attr('selected','selected');
    }

    });

</script>
```